# WSO2 Identity Server and WSO2 API Manager integration - ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have integrated API M and Id Server using the prepackaged version
I have started Id Server. But while starting API Manager , i am getting the below error

[image]

I have correctly set the offset value as    1 in the carbon.xml...Still i am getting the error..i have passed offset value via command line argument as well..
can someone please help? I am really stuck on this.

Comment: I have tried the command line option to set offset value..thats not working as well... I started WSO2 ID Server first and then tried to start WSO2 API Manager... Then API manager instantaneously failed...

Comment: try killing the processes listening on port 9443, lsof -i :9443 should list them

Comment: 9443 is where WSO2 Id Server runs... I have to run both Id server and API manager togother...
so killing 9443 will kill Id server which is not suitable in my case.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of logs or code. Copy and paste instead.

Comment: Can you start APIM alone, without any errors? If you start APIM first and IS second, you get the same error?

Comment: This is solved i believe.This was because my system JAVA_OPTS was being set to debug mode and WSO2 was starting in debug mode. That caused being listening to port 9999 and the conflict.
I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because my system JAVA_OPTS was being set to debug mode and WSO2 was starting in debug mode. That caused being listening to port 9999 and the conflict. I removed the unnecessary JAVA_OPTS and it solved the issue